# Получить количество подписчиков Facebook (2018)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-api, opengraph

До недавних изменений в политики Facebook, можно было [создать WWW приложение](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) и следующим образом получать количество подписчиков:

```
function getFacebookFollowers($page, $appid, $appsecret) {

    $json_url ='https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page.'?access_token='.$appid.'|'.$appsecret.'&fields=likes';

    $json = file_get_contents($json_url);
    $json_output = json_decode($json);

    if ($json_output->likes) {
        $likes = (intval($json_output->likes) > 1) ? intval($json_output->likes) : 0;
        return $likes;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

На данный момент вариант не работает. Имеется ли другой "легкий" метод получения графы о подписчиках, с учетом того, что большинство страниц недоступны без авторизации в социальной сети?

PS: Также нужны учитывать, что подписчики и лайки **для групп Facebook** это 2 разные графы.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш вариант был допусти́м пару месяцев назад, но в связи с новой политикой конфиденциальности, доступ предоставлен только администраторам сообщества.

Альтернативных способов практически нет, кроме как: сделать велосипед путем прямой авторизации для получения кук, и, с этими куками делать запросы к конкретной странице, откуда можно будет парсить данные о количестве участниках и другую информацию.

Comment: Да знаем) Это и описали выше. Относительно парсера и кук, не вариант, не одобряем подобное. Щас даже такая ситуация, что для администраторов тоже усложнена данная процедура. Хочеться найти метод, который позволил бы одним запросом как авторизоваться (токеном или ключем) так и получить данные. А не отдельно авторизоваться, обновлять токены и уже после работать. Для получения 1 цифры делать столько телодвижений как-то не очень целесообразно получается.

Comment: @PerfectoWeb, ну, думаю можно написать класс для прямой авторизации не париться, устанавливать переавторизацию, скажем, где-то каждые 2 часа. Тем более с этой штукой (классом) можно тащить информацию, которой нет в API, ну это имхо конечно. Но пока никаких альтернатив не вижу, к сожалению :)